# Eclipse (Pulsar) packaging: How do I incorporate other projects into my jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, java-me

I have a JavaME project in Eclipse (Pulsar 3.5; Galileo).

I have another project with common code in it in the same workspace and this is referenced from my app.

When I choose 'package app' it generates a jad/jar in the project's deployed folder, but the classes from the referenced project are not included.

Is it possible to include these classes into the final jar automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sooner had I asked the question, than I found the solution myself...

Project properties, 'Order and Export', check the box next to the referenced project you want to include in the output.